# Is there a way of sending emails by a second account which is only shared with Outlook Interop Library?

Tags: c#, outlook

Is there a way where we could send E-Mail's via the Microsoft Interop Outlook Library by using the second mail like in this picture?

[image]

Whenever I tried sending E-Mails by the second folder, it uses the standard folder.

```
_Outlook.Folder folder = (_Outlook.Folder)outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.Folders[1];

_Outlook.AppointmentItem agendaMeeting = (_Outlook.AppointmentItem)folder.Application.CreateItem(_Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do not hardcode the indices (e.g. `Session.Folders[1]`) - retrieve the stores by name.

If you already have `MAPIFolder`, call `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` instead of `Application.CreateItem`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Items` collections of the folder (Calendar folder in our case), not `Application`. The `Add` method accepts the `OlItemType` enumeration too and returns a newly created Outlook item.

```
_Outlook.AppointmentItem agendaMeeting = (_Outlook.AppointmentItem)folder.Application.CreateItem(_Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
```

Read more about possible ways of creating calendar items in the [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article.